# SQL analytical functions first value over max(another atribute)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `month_totals`, which looks like:

```
Name      DateFrom       Total                      
a         2017-01-01     34      
b         2017-01-01     54           
a         2017-02-01     22             
b         2017-02-01     12
a         2017-03-01     34      
b         2017-03-01     54
```

How to select latest `Totals` per `Name` `where DateFrom < '2017-03-01'` (possibly using analytical functions)

Following statement does not work as expected

```
 SELECT name,
       First_value(total)
         OVER (
           ORDER BY Max(datefrom) DESC)
FROM   month_totals
WHERE datefrom < '2017-03-01'
GROUP  BY NAME
```

The desired result should be

```
Name           Total                               
a              22             
b              12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below using min aggregation

```
 SELECT name,min(total) 
    FROM   month_totals
   GROUP  BY NAME
```

OR you can use row_number()

```
select * from
(
SELECT name,
       row_number() over(partition by name order by total)rn
FROM   month_totals
WHERE datefrom < '2017-03-01'
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use window functions, I think a correlated subquery is a simple-enough way to write the query and should have good performance;

```
select mt.*
from month_totals mt
where mt.datefrom = (select max(mt2.datefrom)
                     from month_totals mt2
                     where mt2.name = mt.name and mt2.datefrom < '2017-03-01'
                    );
```

Comment: You could wrap Gordon’s solution in an SProc and pass the 2017-03-01 value in as a parameter.